# Diophantine consequences of the Buzzard–Diamond–Jarvis conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, diophantine-equations, galois-representations

[Serre's modularity conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_modularity_conjecture) famously implies Fermat Last Theorem. More generally, Serre's conjecture implies that certain generalized Fermat equations have no non-trivial solutions (see Section 4.1 of these [notes by Darmon](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/02.Serre-conjecture/paper.pdf)).

The [Buzzard-Diamond-Jarvis conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2106) is a generalization of Serre's modularity conjecture to Hilbert modular forms.

**Question:** Is the Buzzard-Diamand-Jarvis conjecture known to imply the solution of any Diophantine equations?

Comment: I suspect it will have connections to Diophantine equations over number fields other than $\mathbb Q$. There is a (still evolving) theory of Fermat equations over other number fields. Modularity questions are important (like in the version over $\mathbb Q$) but they are not the full story (analogues of other steps in the proof become harder as well), so I don't think they *quite* give an answer to your questions. Regardless, I will leave this question to people who know what they are talking about.

Comment: You should maybe read some of the recent work of Samir Siksek and his collaborators about Fermat's equation over totally real fields, which uses modularity results for Hilbert modular forms as a key input. E.g. this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02860.pdf